# REST-UNSUPPORTEDPARAM Issue

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying to create rest endpoint in MarkLogic 9, By just moving marklogic.rest.resources folder from MarkLogic 8 environment to MarkLogic 9.

Following setup were taken care.

```
url-rewriter=/MarkLogic/rest-api/rewriter.xml
error-handler=/MarkLogic/rest-api/error-handler.xqy
rewrite-resolves-globally=true
```

Below snippet of resource.xqy

```
declare %rapi:params(“project=xs:string”) function function menu:put($context as xs:map, $params as xs:map, $input as xs:map) as document-node(){
   element test {‘test’}
};
```

When I am trying to invoke the endpoint, it’s saying:

```
REST-UNSUPPORTEDPARAM: (err:FOER0000) Endpoint does not support query parameter: invalid parameters: project for menu
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide more detail about the issue?

Are you upgrading from MarkLogic 8 to MarkLogic 9?  If so, the upgrade operation should take care of all issues?

Are you trying to copying a resource service extension from a MarkLogic 8 instance to a MarkLogic 9 instance?  If so, you should install the resource service extension by means of the REST API /v1/config/resources endpoint on the MarkLogi 9 instance.

Does the REST request pass the parameter with the rs: prefix?  That's required.

Comment: Thanks for response.It was helpful. I found the issue based on your comment, rs: prefix is missing from the request. once I added it worked. Is there any way we can ignore sending rs: in ML9? rs: was not required with ML 8 since most of my rest endpoints are working in 8 without rs:

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there was a validation added to catch un-prefixed user params in 9.